# Struggling with Layout element order of Pie menus

Tags: python, scripting, interface, pie-menu

I am sensing that there is an order or format issue in my script. The following sequence results into this pie layout with the two last commands starting at the 2 position.

[image]

```
        box = pie.split().column()
        row = box.row()
        box.operator("MESH_OT_faces_shade_smooth", text="Mesh Smooth")
        box.operator("MESH_OT_faces_shade_flat", text="Mesh Flat")
        box.operator("calculate.normal")
        box.operator("mesh.flip_normals")
        box.prop(mesh, "show_normal_face", text="Face Normal", icon='FACESEL')
        box.prop(mesh, "show_extra_edge_length", text="Face Normal Length")
        box.prop(scene.tool_settings, "normal_size", text="Size")
        row.prop(mesh, "use_auto_smooth")
        row.prop(mesh, "auto_smooth_angle", text="Angle")
```

But I would like them to be in one row byt at the end of the pie menu.

Can somebody explain to me where my flaw in the logic there is?

Comment: related, essentially the same answer, and question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44402/order-of-buttons-drawn-not-matching-code-order/44403#44403

Answer (score 1):

You start with -

```
box = pie.split().column()
row = box.row()
```

Then you add items to the column and then follow it with two properties in the row that you first created at the top.